# How to create an instance of a model and an instance of another model that has foreign key of it at the same time in prisma?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, prisma

Hi I'm trying to create an instance of model `Profile` which has foreign key of an instance of `User` at the same time creating the instance of `Profile` in prisma and nestjs.

Let me explain in more detail.
I have these two models (They are very simplified for ease of thinking.):

```
model User {
  @@map("user")

  id       Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  loginId  String @map("login_id") @unique()
  password String
  profile  Profile
}

model Profile {
  @@map("profile")

  id        Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  firstName String @map("first_name")
  lastName  String @map("last_name")
  userId    Int    @map("user_id") @unique()
  user      User   @relation(references: [id], fields: [userId], onDelete: Cascade)
}
```

Then I want to create a pair of an instance of `User` and an instance of `Profile` at the same time. So I'd like to do like this in my service file:

```
async createUserAndProfile(body) {
  const res = await this.prismaService.$transaction(async(tx) => {
    try {
      const createUser = await tx.user.create({
        data : {
          loginId  : body.loginId,
          password : body.password
        }
      })

      const createProfile = await this.prismaService.profile.create({
        data : {
          firstName : body.firstName,
          lastName  : body.lastName,
          userId    : createUser.id
        }
      })
       return { createUser, createProfile }
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  })
   return res
}
```

However, I got an error:

```
...
→ 82 const createProfile = await this.prismaService.profile.create(
  Foreign key constraint failed on the field: `profile_user_id_fkey (index)`
...
```

Then I tried to print `userId` after `const createUser...`, and I got an expected userId. So I have no idea why I got the error. Please tell me how can I fix this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the defining `user` model, since a user can exist without a profile, but the profile must be associated with a user exclusively, so please let the profile field optional

```
model User {
  @@map("user")

  id       Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  loginId  String @map("login_id") @unique()
  password String
  profile  Profile?
}
```

so you can create a user first the create a related profile.